# android admob not showing up- screen size too small

Tags: android, layout, uiwebview, admob

I have a webview and an admob ad onthe bottom. It is getting the ad but not displaying it because the screen is too Small. Previosuly , when I ran it in just a `linear layout` the ad would show up fine.

Here is the code i have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical">
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adUnitId="a14e0b54f42c7c7"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
     <WebView
    android:id="@+id/sdrwebview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_above="@+id/ad" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping the views around... your Webview is probably covering the Adview

```
<RelativeLayout...>
     <WebView.../>
     <com.google.ads.AdView.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no luck. it says the same thing in log cat `Not enough space to show ad!`

Comment: any other ideas what it could be?

Comment: Try to find out how much exactly **not enough** is

Comment: the log cat says `Wants: <320, 50> has: <300,371>`. But as I said before It is working if it is just in a linear layour but I think the view is compressing it or something. What do you think?

Comment: I assume you are on mdpi like 320x480. Why is it you only got a width of 300px it should be 320px. Try to figure out where you lose those 20. You probably use some margin or padding in your layout.

Comment: as far as i'm concerned there is no margin or padding in my layout. see the code above

Comment: Just for testing replace android:layout_width="fill_parent" with android:layout_width="320dp" in the RelativeLayout as well as in both Views.

Comment: So i tried what you suggested and the ad now appears on the screen. The ad goes of the screen still for some reason and the webview is now, due to the changes, not taking up the whole screen. hmmm

Comment: Setting it to 320dp also worked for me. But how did you made it device independent or really fix that issue? I removed the padding of the layout and the adView via setPadding(0,0,0,0) but it still complains that the area is too small

Answer (score 0):

See the AdMob documentation. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#play

> The SDK will request whatever size the requesting AdView was instantiated with. If there isn't enough space on the device's screen to display the ad, nothing will be shown.

Maybe the AdMob SDK doesn't support smaller screens than 320x50.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following

```
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```